# How to remove spare tire / wheel when the plastic retainer won't unscrew?

Tags: tires

I have a spare wheel that I need to take out of the trunk of my Nissan Pulsar, but the middle bit always slips when I try turning it.

[image: spare wheel]

I think it's fixed too tightly. How do I remove this thing?

Comment: Can you add another photo at a lower angle to show depth?

Comment: It seems to me that this plastic blue cap is only a securing mechanism and underneath is the proper nut that will release it.

Answer (score 10):

The blue plastic spacer (that keeps the wheel central) has split so it slips around the bolt head.

Prise the plastic part out (you'll have to break it) so that you can undo the bolt directly. Then replace the plastic surround.

Alternatively, you could try gripping the bolt head and its plastic surround with a mole wrench and undoing it that way, but it still needs a new plastic part.

Don't tighten it hard, only by hand (it's a handle), just enough to hold the wheel in place. First, apply a very small smear of grease to the threads at the tip of the bolt to make it easier to undo next time.